# Logging in grails integration test?

Tags: logging, grails, groovy, junit

I'm using grails 1.3.6, and no matter what I do, I can't get log.* statements output to the console.

Test:

```
class MyObjectTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    MyObjectTests myObjectTests

    public void testSomething(){ myObjectTests.something() }
}
```

Class:

```
class MyObject {
  void something(){
     log.info( "Hello." )
  }
}
```

I've tried using GrailsUnitTestCase and mockLogging, but that doesn't work either. Only `println` sends anything to the console. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6858 and it's fixed in 1.3.7. You should upgrade if possible, but there are workarounds in the JIRA comments.

Comment: :/. I can't upgrade to 1.3.7 due to another regression.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but since it's testing-related one of the workarounds in the comments will work since it doesn't involve anything that needs to end up in the deployed war.